# Parts of image behave as div HTML CSS

Tags: css, image, html

I would like to design some sort of a map, of a country, in which every state behaves as a different 'div'. Then I would link different pages to each of the states. But the borders of the state are not square/rectangle/any_regular_shape. The borders are complex shapes. How do I go about doing this?
Even though I break them in Photoshop, how do I recombine them perfectly in CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean image map ? p.s. Photoshop can output HTML with slices in Save for Web & Device feature

Answer (score 1):

You want something like [this map](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html), you should go for SVG and maybe [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HTML image map:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/image_maps/article.php/3479741
Lots of good tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [D3.js Geo Projections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections). [This post written by one of the main developers behind D3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) should be a good start.